# Reading two Json Files and merging them in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, streamreader, system.io.file

I am trying to read 2 json files using `StreamReader`, parse them as `JObject`s and then perform a merge. However I have am receiving the following error when `StreamReader` is called for the second time:

> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not
>   an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.
>
> For the line:
>       string jsonUpdateFile = updatesr.ReadToEnd();

The code below:

```
var path = String.Format("{0}json\\data.json", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
string jsonOldFile = new StreamReader(path).ReadToEnd();

var updatepath = String.Format("{0}json\\update.json", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
string jsonUpdateFile = new StreamReader(updatepath).ReadToEnd();

var jsonO = JObject.Parse(jsonOldFile);
var jsonU = JObject.Parse(jsonUpdateFile);

//merge new json into old json
jsonO.Merge(jsonU);


//save to file
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
file.Directory.Create();
string JsonToSave = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonO);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@path, JsonToSave);
```

What I am trying to do with the merge:

```
var jsonO = [{"id":"1234","name":"Bruce"},{"id":"5678","name":"Clark"}] 
var jsonU = [{"id":"1234","name":"Wayne"}] 

var merge = [{"id":"1234","name":"Wayne"},{"id":"5678","name":"Clark"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take JArray and add the second Json to First One i.e, Like this one

```
var jsonO = JArray.Parse(jsonOldFile);
var jsonU = JArray.Parse(jsonUpdateFile);

foreach(JObject innerData in jsonU ) 
{
    jsonO.Add(innerData);
}
```

In order to Update the other json I think you can try this one i dont know once give it a shot

```
    var jsonO = JArray.Parse(jsonOldFile);
    var jsonU = JArray.Parse(jsonUpdateFile);
    var item = jsonO.Children<JObject>();

    foreach(JObject innerData in jsonU)
    {
          if(innerData[Id] == item[Id])
           {
              item[Name] = innerData[Name];
              jsonO.Replace(item["Name"]);
              //[or]
              jsonO.Add(item["Name"});
           }
          else
           {
              jsonO.Add(innerData);
           }
    }
```

even i'm a newbie if i'm wrong please do correct me happy to learn it ..

Comment: This looks promising, how would I get this working so an update occurs if both arrays have an element with matching id values like so.

var jsonO =  [{"id":"1234","name":"Bruce"},{"id":"5678","name":"Clark"}]
var jsonU =  [{"id":"1234","name":"Wayne"}]

var merge =  [{"id":"1234","name":"Wayne"},{"id":"5678","name":"Clark"}

Comment: I've Updated my code please check it and try it once @tama

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonO = JArray.Parse(jsonOldFile);
var jsonU = JArray.Parse(jsonUpdateFile);
```

Using JArray rather than JObject allows me to read the files in. Merge doesn't work as expected but that's a question for another thread.

Comment: 1) For options in merging arrays, check out [Merging JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm) and [MergeArrayHandling Enumeration](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_MergeArrayHandling.htm).  2) If you don't know in advance whether your root JSON container is an object or array, use `JToken.Parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the error stated in question, my guess is that your `update.json` file is not in a valid json format. Please use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json first.